# spaces between name of fields

Tags: php, http, parameters, urldecode

hello i am working on codeigniter  an iam getting problem that when anyone go to edit name that was entered as "XYZ ABC" means providing space between them then we get "%20"  as printed between them when it is printed on textfield to be edited

Comment: Show us at least a reduced code with your HTML and PHP

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the user input get url_encoded somwhere, as `%20` is an urlencoded whitespace.
Try decoding it before displaying/writing to DB:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
echo urldecode($str);
```

[read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)